# Golang timeout is not executed with channels

Tags: go, timeout, channel

I am using goroutines/channels.
Here is my code.
Why is the timeout case not getting executed?

```
func main() {
    c1 := make(chan int, 1)

    go func() {
        for {
            time.Sleep(1500 * time.Millisecond)
            c1 <- 10
        }
    }()

    go func() {
        for {
            select {
            case i := <-c1:
                fmt.Println(i)
            case <-time.After(2000 * time.Millisecond):
                fmt.Println("TIMEOUT") // <-- Not Executed
            }
        }
    }()

    fmt.Scanln()
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your timeout doesn't happen, because one of your goroutine sends a value on your `c1` channel in every 1.5 seconds (or so) repeatedly, and your timeout would only happen if there is no value to be received from `c1` for 2 seconds.

Once a value is received from `c1`, in the next iteration executing `select` again a **new** `time.After()` call will be made which which returns a **new** channel on which a value will only be sent after another 2 seconds. The timeout channel from the previous `select` execution is discarded and is not used anymore.

To receive the timeout after 2 seconds, create the timeout channel only once, e.g.:

```
timeout := time.After(2000 * time.Millisecond)
for {
    select {
    case i := <-c1:
        fmt.Println(i)
    case <-timeout:
        fmt.Println("TIMEOUT") // Will get executed after 2 sec
    }
}
```

Output:

```
10
TIMEOUT
10
10
10
...
```