# Why doesn't this Golang code to select among multiple time.After channels work?

Tags: time, go, timeout, channel

Why doesn't this Golang code to select among multiple time.After channels work?

See code below. The 'timeout' message is never issued. Why?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    count := 0
    for {
        select {
        case <-time.After(1 * time.Second):
            count++
            fmt.Printf("tick %d\n", count)
            if count >= 5 {
                fmt.Printf("ugh\n")
                return
            }
        case <-time.After(3 * time.Second):
            fmt.Printf("timeout\n")
            return
        }
    }
}
```

Run it on Playground: http://play.golang.org/p/1gku-CWVAh

Output:

```
tick 1
tick 2
tick 3
tick 4
tick 5
ugh
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [golang timeouts is not executed with channels](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34894927/golang-timeouts-is-not-executed-with-channels)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Because `time.After` is a function, so on every iteration it returns a new channel. If you want this channel to be the same for all iterations, you should save it before the loop:

```
timeout := time.After(3 * time.Second)
for {
    select {
    //...
    case <-timeout:
        fmt.Printf("timeout\n")
        return
    }
}
```

Playground: http://play.golang.org/p/muWLgTxpNf.

Comment: Great! I was creating multiple channels! Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Even [@Ainar-G](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1892060/ainar-g) has already provided the answer, another possibility is to use `time.Tick(1e9)` to generate a time tick on every second and then listen for `timeAfter`channel after the specified period.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    count := 0
    timeTick := time.Tick(1 * time.Second)
    timeAfter := time.After(5 * time.Second)

    for {
        select {
        case <-timeTick:
            count++
            fmt.Printf("tick %d\n", count)
            if count >= 5 {
                fmt.Printf("ugh\n")
                return
            }
        case <-timeAfter:
            fmt.Printf("timeout\n")
            return
        }
    }
}
```